# When I try to use LazyHStack cannot dynamic content height

Tags: swiftui

```
struct HomeTrendingProductsView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm: HomeTrendingProductsVM = .init()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                trendingProductList
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            }
            
            Spacer().frame(height: 36)
            
        }
    }
}

extension HomeTrendingProductsView {
    @ViewBuilder
    var trendingProductList: some View {
        LazyHStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 24) {
            ForEach(Array(zip(vm.output.trendingProducts.indices, vm.output.trendingProducts)), id: \.0) { index, product in
                TrendingProductCard(product: product)
                .frame(width: 136)
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[when I using HStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mlia.png)

[when I using LazyHStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjxwp.png)

When I try to use LazyHStack in trendingProductList, it cannot be dynamic content height.
But HStack is works, It looks like simple code. I am so confused.